# How to select a child element inside a div using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to select a child element inside a div this is my html code:

```
<div class='body'>
  <text>This is a text element</text>
</div>
```

I want to select the text element instead of ading a class or an id. Sorry I am new to css and html please help

Comment: There is no `<text>` element in HTML

Comment: Have you tried searching for "child" in the CSS [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/)?

Comment: [**This LINK might be of use**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Comment: A quick search in your favorite search engine would have provided hundreds of good tutorials on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select a child element inside a div you would use `>`

This is the code:

```
.body > text{
   color : blue;
}
```

This is simple CSS